# How do you search for strings within a string?

Tags: python, string, indexing

I'm writing a pig latin decoder. This section works with 'qu' works but currently only is the third letter of the word is a vowel. I am implementing an if statement to get it to work for words that have a consonant as the third letter, but keep getting this error: **TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list**

Here is my code:

```
if w[-2:] == 'ay':
        RegW = []
        y = w.find('-')
        beginningw = w[y:]
        if vowel not in beginningw[0]:
            RegW.append(beginningw[0:-2] + w[0:y])
        else:
            RegW.append('qu' + w[0:y])
        return RegW[0]
```

It works for these word:
ay-quay (quay)
iz-quay (quiz)
eue-quay (queue)

but NOT an-quray (quran) (returns quan w/o if statement I'm trying to)

Comment: Where did you define variable `vowel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `vowel` is a list of vowel characters, I think you want this:

```
if beginningw[0] not in vowel:
```